# JSON Object creation is failing

Tags: java, android, json

I have json file which i down from internet and saved to my app. Then i read this file and create json object . But i am not able to create json object .
 This is the exception I am getting

org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 3 of { \"resources\": { ..........

Below is my code to read input stream and create json object

```
 private JSONObject readFileFromInpputStream(InputStream inst) throws JSONException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder=null;
        try { 
            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inst, "UTF-8")); 
            responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null){
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);  
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str = responseStrBuilder.toString();
        String k=str.replace("\"", "\\\"");
       // String m =k.replaceAll("\t", "");
       // String s= m.replaceAll("\n", "");
        //String p = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        Log.i(loggerName, loggerName + " str " +str);
        //Log.i(loggerName, loggerName + " k " +p);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(k);
        return obj;
    }
```

Below is output string

```
   {
    "resources": {
        "-xmlns:xliff": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2",
        "string": [
            {
                "name": "sample1",
                "value": "To <xliff:g id=\"receiver_name\"> Europe </xliff:g>"
            },
            {
                "name": "cdata",
                "value": "<![CDATA[<p>Text<p>]]>"
            },
            {
                "name": "content_description_sample",
                "value": " <b>Something</b>"
            },
            {
                "name": "countdown",
                "value": " <xliff:g id="time" example="5days">%1$s</xliff:g> until holiday"
            },
            {
                "name": "picker_combined_view_fmt",
                "value": " Combined view (<xliff:g id="count">%s</xliff:g>)"
            },
            {
                "name": "configure_email_text",
                "value": "No corporate email accounts have been configured on this device. To configure them, click <b>Here</b> "
            },
            {
                "name": "invalid_credentials",
                "value": "Authentication failed. Enter valid credentials."
            },
            {
                "name": "link",
                "value": "<b>Hello World</b> This is a test of the URL <a href=\"http://www.example.com/\">Example</a>"
            },
            {
                "name": "bold",
                "value": "<b>This text is bold</b>"
            },
            {
                "name": "emphasis",
                "value": "<em>This text is emphasized</em>"
            },
            {
                "name": "check_availability_button",
                "value": "Check availability How are you"
            }
        ],
        "string-array": [
            {
                "name": "Array1",
                "item": [
                    "en_US",
                    "en_GB"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Array2",
                "item": [
                    "en_US",
                    "en_GB"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}{
    \"resources\": {
        \"-xmlns: xliff\": \"urn: oasis: names: tc: xliff: document: 1.2\",
        \"string\": [
            {
                \"name\": \"sample1\",
                \"value\": \"To<xliff: gid=\\"receiver_name\\">Europe</xliff: g>\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"cdata\",
                \"value\": \"<![
                    CDATA[
                        <p>Text<p>
                    ]
                ]>\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"content_description_sample\",
                \"value\": \"<b>Something</b>\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"countdown\",
                \"value\": \"<xliff: gid=\"time\"example=\"5days\">%1$s</xliff: g>untilholiday\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"picker_combined_view_fmt\",
                \"value\": \"Combinedview(<xliff: gid=\"count\">%s</xliff: g>)\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"configure_email_text\",
                \"value\": \"Nocorporateemailaccountshavebeenconfiguredonthisdevice.Toconfigurethem,
                click<b>Here</b>\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"invalid_credentials\",
                \"value\": \"Authenticationfailed.Entervalidcredentials.\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"link\",
                \"value\": \"<b>HelloWorld</b>ThisisatestoftheURL<ahref=\\"http: //www.example.com/\\">Example</a>\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"bold\",
                \"value\": \"<b>Thistextisbold</b>\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"emphasis\",
                \"value\": \"<em>Thistextisemphasized</em>\"
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"check_availability_button\",
                \"value\": \"CheckavailabilityHowareyou\"
            }
        ],
        \"string-array\": [
            {
                \"name\": \"Array1\",
                \"item\": [
                    \"en_US\",
                    \"en_GB\"
                ]
            },
            {
                \"name\": \"Array2\",
                \"item\": [
                    \"en_US\",
                    \"en_GB\"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and below is the exception i am getting

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 3 of {  \"resources\": { ..........
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem I got, I think you just converted a XML to JSON. They will convert attributes to JSON string which starts with {"-attribute",11} we will get a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to escape quotation marks("). They are part of how the json object constructor identifies strings.

Just using

`JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);`

should be fine.

In addition,

in " Combined view (%s)" the two quotation marks are treated as string delimiters and SHOULD be escaped, but it indicates a problem with the server you got this message from. Escaping these yourself can be impossible because there is no sure way to know which quotation marks are real and which are part of the text.

Comment: If i do not replace that I get following error . org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 447 of

Comment: @AnujKumarJha that means that you are missing a "{" or a a "}". You still shouldn't escape the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

On validating your JSON output through [Jlint](http://jsonlint.com/) it gives validation error, but on removing space on line 2 of your output(is the space  intentional ? or you added it on posting question by mistake?)

```
 "cdata", "value": "Text

]]>" }, { "nam
```

it validates successfully.

In any case whether the space is initial source of error or not ,like CurlyCorvus said, simply pass the String to `new JSONObject(str);` without escaping the `"`.

Comment: If i do not replace that I get following error .
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 447 of

Comment: Your json is correct (without the spaces), pass it as it is to the JSONObject() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Thans Mustafa and Curly.

The issue was due to quotes mark in  tag 
for ex in original one value is 
"value": " %1$s until holiday"

It worked fine when I replaced it to 
"value": " %1$s until holiday"

So I guess when quotes is present inside it consider it as new object.